# Open file under cursor declared as #include in the C/C++ code in Vim?

Tags: file, vim

I now how I can open a file under cursor in Vim.

Is there any way to also open files declared like below?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "limits.h"
```

Comment: move cursor to limits.h and try typing `gf`, however i don't know the way to open iostream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

- <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to edit the file name under the cursor in the current window (requires `'nomodified'` on the existing buffer in the current window).
- <kbd>^w</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to edit the file name under the cursor in a new window. (Note: conveniently, <kbd>^w</kbd><kbd>^f</kbd> also works.)
- <kbd>^w</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to edit the file name under the cursor in a new tab page.

For this to work, your `'path'` setting must contain the location of the target file.

To give an example, here's my `'path'` on my current system:

```
.,/usr/include,,
```

Because `limits.h` is located at `/usr/include/limits.h`, it works automatically.

However, because `iostream` is located at `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/iostream`, it does *not* work automatically. But I can run

```
set path+=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++
```

to change it to

```
.,/usr/include,,,/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++
```

and now it works. The exact path will likely differ on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Move cursor to the filename and try to use <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> in normal mode.

See `:h gf` for additional info. Probably you need to set options `path`, `suffixesadd`, etc.

Comment: `:set path+=/usr/include/c++/4.9` and `gf` opens `iostream`.